# Will lightning apps written in Javascript also work in VF

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforce-classic

I am a product owner/entrepreneur looking to build an app for salesforce that we will distribute through App Exchange. We are trying to decide if we can use Lightning or VisualForce, Question is, if we write our app to Lightning standards can Classic/VF users use it?

Comment: I would suggest you adopt LWC and Lightning Experience for anything new. Visuaforce is not the way forward for Salesforce and the Classic Experience will be turned off at some point in the relatively near future.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, if you are creating custom component then you can not directly access that in classic mode.

You have to use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html) or you should prefer to create complete functionality in Visual Force page with SLDS to give lightning style.

If that is standard page then it will be accessible in classic mode as well.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: this is personal opinion based on working for a Salesforce Partner.

With the assumption that your app is greenfield development, I would **strongly** recommend creating it for Lightning Experience and using Lightning Web Components. If users have other pages that are Visualforce, as part of the Subscriber Org (perhaps custom or from some third-party packages), these can still be accessed in Lightning Experience (as long as they are marked as available). Yes, many Lightning features require use of Lightning Experience but this is the way forward.

As Dhanik Lal Sahni said, if you provide some custom components it is possible to integrate these into Visualforce pages (but note that a Visualforce page cannot be embedded within a Lightning Web Component).

Lightning Web Components are far easier to develop than Lighting (Aura) Components, in my experience - once you have your head around how wired functions work. They are also easier than Visualforce when you have any complex UX or behavioural needs in your page. They also interact with the Org more efficiently.

Starting a greenfield app/package development using Visualforce would not be the right approach, IMHO, since this technology is effectively 2 generations old. Salesforce are full ahead with Lightning Experience and LWC, in "keep it going for now" mode with Lightning Aura whilst in "maintenance" mode for Visualforce from what I have seen.

Comment: Was just about to write the same.